# Eclipse preference settings, precedence and changing default value

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I'm creating an Eclipseinstallation with some preinstalled plugins and to that I'm trying to set preferences to some default values. Preferences are being set in a plugin_customization.ini file, and Eclipse starts up with

```
-pluginCustomization
plugins/<my_plugin>/plugin_customization.ini
```

I have verified that some of the values in the ini file do work, but a certain setting is not being set. It's most likely due to that setting is not part of the original preferences, but is being added by a plugin. Presumably this plugin then sets a default value, and that default value is incorrect and I need to override it.

So this leads to question 1, what is the precedence for setting preferences in Eclipse? 
My guess is;

1. Commandline argument -pluginCustomization
2. Plugin sets preferences in code
3. Saved workspace settings

Are there more alternatives?

Question 2; If I need to make sure that a certain preference value is set and not overwritten by another plugin, what are my options?